# PostgreSQL: Crear usuarios que empiecen con número

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos PostgreSQL y quiero guardar a los usuario con los números de DNI.

El problema es que no me deja guardarlo si empieza con número. ¿Alguien me podría decir si es posible que empiece con número?

```
create user 12345 with encrypted password 'Admin1234'


ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «12345»
LINE 1: create user 12345 with encrypted password 'Admin1234'
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear el usuario usando comillas alrededor del nombre.

```
CREATE USER "12345" WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'Admin1234'
```

Comment: deben ser comillas simples

Comment: ¿Por qué? Las comillas simples son para definir una cadena de caracteres (como en la contraseña), pero las comillas dobles son para nombre identificadores.

Comment: Con las comillas dobles me deja crear el usuario, pero no me deja borrarlo, la consola me dice lo siguiente: ERROR:  no existe el rol «1234» He probado con --drop owned by "1234"-- y --drop user "1234"-- @LuisCazares

Comment: Y puedes confirmar que en realidad existe?